# Confusing TypeScript definition

Tags: typescript

I found this in a definition file and I am bit perplexed, how exactly is this supposed to be used?

```
interface Curve {
    [index: number]: Point;
}
```

where Point is

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

**So the Curve is a class, right? But what is the array of Points, a method? how do I use it? What is the index in the array?**

It is may not be relevant but the Curve is meant to be passed to a Bezier library like this:

```
interface JSBezier {
    distanceFromCurve(curve: Curve, point: Point): number;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as index signatures.

This one

```
interface Curve {
    [index: number]: Point;
}
```

means that if you index a curve by a number you get a point. i.e.

```
var foo:Curve;
var bar = foo [0]; // bar is inferred to be a Point
```

Comment: sorry but where is the Point? How do I define the Curve? do I assign Point to the index like foo[0] = new Point()?

Comment: `interface`s are not `class`es

Answer (score 2):

Even though there is only an interface such as `Point`, the TypeScript compiler will confirm that an object has a compatible signature at compile time.

So, when you see:

```
interface Curve {
    [index: number]: Point;
}
```

This means that there is an indexable property that accepts `numbers` and that the right hand side will always conform to the `Point` interface. Index signatures  are defined in 3.7.4 of the TypeScript language specification.

It does not mean that an object won't also support indexed properties of type `string`, but that when they are `number`s, they will be compatible with the `Point` interface.

Also, it means that if you have a class instance (`Curve` can be instantiated because it only has an index signature and no other properties/methods that it also must implement):

```
var c : Curve = {};
```

You can set new `Point`s as long as they match the interface:

```
c[1] = { x: 1, y: 100 };
```

In the above, the index `1` has been assigned to a new object that matches the `Point` interface (as it has an `x` and a `y` property both of type numbers). You can also do:

```
c[2] = { x: 1, y: 100, z: -10 };
```

While there is another property, `z`, the object instance is still a `Point` by having `x` and `y`.